# instead of id use firstname+lastname+email in select list asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have feedback form with two fields : project_name and lastName of partner. The first fiels is correct(project_name) but instead lastName of second field I want there firstName+lastName+email, how to do it? At the moment there is only lastname, but I can have multiply lastnames for different partners. Below is sample of code how I create this form.

In my create method of feedbackController:

```
  ViewBag.project_id = new SelectList(db.Projects.Where(p => p.project_id == project_id), "project_id", "name");
  ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Users_projects.Where(p => p.project_id == project_id && p.project_role == "partner").Select(up => new { up.AspNetUsers.FirstName,up.AspNetUsers.LastName, up.AspNetUsers.Id }), "Id", "LastName");
```

Here is my view how render this form:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4></h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.project_id, "Project: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("project_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, " For partner : ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ViewBag.Id =db.Users_projects
   .Where(p => p.project_id == project_id &&p.project_role == "partner")
   .Select(up =>
   new SelectListItem {
                     // You may append User email also here
                     Text= up.AspNetUsers.FirstName +" "+up.AspNetUsers.LastName,
                     Value = up.AspNetUsers.Id.ToString() })
   .ToList();
```

You can make your code more readable/maintainable by not using dynamic stuff like ViewBag and switch to a strongly typed viewmodel to pass the data between your action method and view

```
public class AssignProjectOwnerShipVm
{
  public int SelectedPartner {set;get;}
  public int SelectedProject {set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Projects {set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Partners {set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action

```
pubilc ActionResult AssignProject()
{
  var vm = new AssignProjectOwnerShipVm();
  vm.Projects = db.Projects.Select(s=>new SelectListItem
                      {
                        Value = s.ProjectId.ToString(),
                        Text = s.ProjectName 
                      }).ToList();
  vm.Partners=db.Users_projects
       .Where(p => p.project_id == project_id &&p.project_role == "partner")
       .Select(up =>
       new SelectListItem {
                     // You may append User email also here
                     Text= up.AspNetUsers.FirstName +" "+up.AspNetUsers.LastName,
                     Value = up.AspNetUsers.Id.ToString() })
   .ToList();

 return View(vm);
}
```

And your view

```
@model AssignProjectOwnerShipVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DrowpDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedProject,Model.Projects,"Select one")
  @Html.DrowpDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedPartner,Model.Partners,"Select one")
<input type="submit" />

}
```

And your HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AssignProjecct(AssignProjectOWnerShipVm model)
{
  // check for model.SelectedParter and model.SelectedProject
 // to do  :Save and redirect
}
```